# Postgres reverse LIKE lookup indexing and performance

Tags: postgresql, indexing

We have a musicians table containing records with multiple string fields, say:

- "Jimi", "Hendrix", "Guitar"
- "Phil", "Collins", "Drums"
- "Sting", "", "Bass"
- "Ringo", "Starr", "Drums"
- "Paul", "McCartney", "Bass"

I want to pass postgres a long string, say:

> "It is known that Jimi liked to set light to his guitar and smash up
>   all the drums while on stage."

and i want to get returned the fields that have any matches - preferably in order of the most matches first:

- "**Jimi**", "Hendrix", "**Guitar**"
- "Phil", "Collins", "**Drums**"
- "Ringo", "Starr", "**Drums**"

because i need the search to be case insensitive, i'm constructing a query like this...

```
select * from musicians where lowercase_string like '%'||firstname||'%' or  lowercase_string like '%'||lastname||'%' or lowercase_string like '%'||instrument||'%'
```

and then looping through (in ruby in my case) to capture the result with the most matches.

this is however very slow in the sql stage (1 minute+).

i've tried adding lower-case GIN index using pg_trgm as suggested [here](https://niallburkley.com/blog/index-columns-for-like-in-postgres/) - but it's not helping - presumably because the like query is back to front?

Thanks!

Comment: What if the "long string" contains `drum`, instead of `drums`? Is [full text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html) acceptable? (It has a [similar, but more configurable ranking system](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-RANKING)).

Comment: i think that would be fine - false positives could be filtered later - but how would full text search work when the "text" is outside of postgres? maybe i've misunderstood how it works?

Comment: What do you mean by *outside of postgres*? In your example `lowercase_string` seems to be "inside" postgres :) -- Obviously, just use/bind it as a query parameter (which depends on your client). With prepared statements, it seems something like `ORDER BY ts_rank(to_tsvector(?), plainto_tsquery(firstname) || plainto_tsquery(lastname) || ...)` in most DBALs.

Comment: And you could filter the results with FTS too, there is no need to filter "false positives" later.

Comment: Maybe worth to mention that neither FTS, nor `pg_trgm`+`LIKE` will use any index, because of your "reverse" matching. -- But if you don't need to loop through the results in ruby, you'll increase the performance anyway. And you could still choose the `simple` dictionary in FTS to make `drum` & `drums` distinct.

Comment: ah - my fault - i put lowercase_string for the sake of clarity - otherwise i'd have had to write "It is known that Jimi liked ..." out 3 times... but yes, i'd normally just bind it as a parameter

Comment: is there some way to add an index on the firstname varchar field that will help this query:
SELECT * from musicians where to_tsvector('Jimi liked ..') @@ plainto_tsquery(firstname)
?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With my testing, it seems that **no trigram index could help your query at all**. And no other index type could possibly speed up an (I)LIKE / FTS based search.

I should mention that all of the queries below use the trigram indexes, when they are queried "reversed": when the table contains the *document* (which is indexed), and your parameter is the *query*. The (I)LIKE variant variant f.ex. 2-3 times faster with it.

These the queries I've tested:

```
select *
from   musicians
where  :input_string ilike '%' || firstname  || '%'
or     :input_string ilike '%' || lastname   || '%'
or     :input_string ilike '%' || instrument || '%'
```

At first, FTS seemed a great idea, but my testing shows that even without ranking, it is 60-100 times slower than the (I)LIKE variant. (So even, when you don't have to post-process results with these methods, these are not worth it).

```
select *
from   musicians
where  to_tsvector(:input_string) @@ (plainto_tsquery(firstname) || plainto_tsquery(lastname) || plainto_tsquery(lastname))
```

However, `ORDER BY rank` doesn't slow down that much further: it is 70-120 times slower than the (I)LIKE variant.

```
select   *
from     musicians
where    to_tsvector(:input_string) @@ (plainto_tsquery(firstname) || plainto_tsquery(lastname) || plainto_tsquery(lastname))
order by ts_rank(to_tsvector(:input_string), plainto_tsquery(firstname) || plainto_tsquery(lastname) || plainto_tsquery(lastname))
```

Then, for a last effort, I tried the (fairly new) "word similarity" operators of the trigram module: `<%` and `%>` (available from PostgreSQL 9.6).

```
select *
from   musicians
where  :input_string %> firstname
or     :input_string %> lastname
or     :input_string %> instrument

select *
from   musicians
where  firstname  <% :input_string
or     lastname   <% :input_string
or     instrument <% :input_string
```

These were somewhat faster then FTS: around 50-70 times slower than the (I)LIKE variant.

(Partially working) [rextester](http://rextester.com/YONN49814): it is run against PostgreSQL 9.5, so the 9.6 operators obviously won't run here.

***Update***: **IF** full word match is enough for you, you can actually reverse your query, to be able to use indexes. You'll need to "parse" your query (aka. "long string") though:

```
with long_string(ls) as (
  values (:input_string)
),
words(word) as (
  select s
  from   long_string, regexp_split_to_table(ls, '[^[:alnum:]]+') s
  where  s <> ''
)
select   musicians.*
from     musicians, words
where    firstname  ilike word
or       lastname   ilike word
or       instrument ilike word
group by musicians.id
```

Note: I parsed the query for every complete word. You can have some other logic there, or it can even be parsed in client side.

The default, `btree` index shines here, as it is much faster than the trigram index with (I)LIKE (we won't need them anyway, as we are looking for complete word match here):

```
with long_string(ls) as (
  values (:input_string)
),
words(word) as (
  select s
  from   long_string, regexp_split_to_table(lower(ls), '[^[:alnum:]]+') s
  where  s <> ''
)
select   musicians.*
from     musicians, words
where    lower(firstname)  = word
or       lower(lastname)   = word
or       lower(instrument) = word
group by musicians.id
```

http://rextester.com/PSABJ6745

You could even get the match count with something like

```
sum((lower(firstname)  = word)::int
  + (lower(lastname)   = word)::int
  + (lower(instrument) = word)::int)
```

Comment: thanks @pozs - my experiments came to the same conclusion: that indexes cannot help me here and that LIKE is the fastest of the slow options...

Comment: @user1051849 If word matches enough for you, you could try to "parse" the query itself (f.ex. split into words by whitespaces) & then try to match word-by-word, like `firstname` ilike 'It' or lastname ilike 'is'`. Or, at this point, you could use the default `btree` indexes & the equality operator `=` for filtering.

Answer (score 2):

The `ilike` option with match ordering:

```
with long_string (ls) as (values
    ('It is known that Jimi liked to set light to his guitar and smash up all the drums while on stage.')
)
select musicians.*, matches
from
    musicians
    cross join
    long_string
    cross join lateral
    (select
        (ls ilike format ('%%%s%%', first_name) and first_name != '')::int +
        (ls ilike format ('%%%s%%', last_name) and last_name != '')::int +
        (ls ilike format ('%%%s%%', instrument) and instrument != '')::int 
        as matches
    ) m
where matches > 0
order by matches desc
;
 first_name | last_name | instrument | matches 
------------+-----------+------------+---------
 Jimi       | Hendrix   | Guitar     |       2
 Phil       | Collins   | Drums      |       1
 Ringo      | Starr     | Drums      |       1
```

Comment: +1, the `first_name != ''` parts are a good catch, and in total, this is a great idea for reducing post-processing costs. It will not, however, reduce the cost of the query itself.